# How can I prevent Spring MVC from adding additional attributes to my JSON?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, jackson

I am using Jackson and a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`  to return JSON from Spring controllers.

When I define a method in Spring like this

```
public ModelMap save(FileUploadBean uploadItem, ParameterBean params) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
```

and return a ModelMap

```
ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
model.addAttribute("output","Save was ok");
return model;
```

Spring allways attaches `uploadItem` and `params` to the JSON response despite I have **never added** these two to ModelMap.

The result looks something like that

```
{
  "parameterBean": {
    "values": {
      "json": "{\"seizure\":{\"id\":1},\"classDocumentType\":{\"id\":1},\"seizureDocumentI18ns\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"comment\":\"123\",\"matLanguageCode\":\"\"}]}"
    }
  },
  "output": ["Save was ok"],
  "fileUploadBean": {
    "file": {
      "originalFilename": "Form.png",
      "fileItem": {
        "contentType": "image/png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this default behaviour, and if where is it described...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced a similar issue-

Check out the following link. I posted a resolution.

[Spring JSON Jackson Marshaller adding additional parameter in my response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978869/spring-json-jackson-marshaller-adding-additional-parameter-in-my-response-object/7979339#7979339)

Comment: @Y Kamesh Rao: thanks for the comment although it doesn't really solve my problem. There should be rather a excludeModelAttributes for [MappingJacksonJsonView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html) in it, unfortunately there isn't, strange that it is default behaviour from Spring JacksonView to attach **ALL** model attributes

Comment: @Y Kamesh Rao, an actually better solution in my case was to subclass MappingJacksonJsonView and override filterModel, got this from a comment here http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/